# How to find bitcoin info

Tags: blockchain.info

Is there a bitcoin or some type of crypto wallet connected with the email addresses guillotine88.mg@gmail.com, handsomematt88@gmail.com or the phone numbers 2109610091, 8302009672, 2105747552, 6129464581?? This is all my info and I thought I had a wallet one time long ago and I’ve been trying to figure it out ever since. Maybe you can help me so I can either use it or move on. Please let me know if you find any info. I should of had close to 64 million back in 2020. So it would be a lot more now.

Comment: Bitcoin wallets generally do not require email addresses or phone numbers for use, and even those that do would generally not make such information public. In any case, it is almost certainly not advisable to post all of your information publicly like this, especially considering the sum of money you've mentioned.

Comment: Be careful, You will be contacted by people claiming to be recovery specialists. They will gain your confidence and then get you confused and put you under time pressure so that you feel compelled to pay them urgent fees.